# templated std::function parameter vs. non template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, std-function

I'm trying to make a function which takes any function returning void and generating a function returning bool by simply calling the original function and returning false.

```
template<typename Arg>
auto voidToBoolTemplate(std::function<void(Arg)> func)
{
    return [&](Arg arg)
    {
        func(arg);
        return false;
    };
}
```

However, I'm having trouble passing lambdas to this function.

```
auto lambda = [](int x)
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
};

voidToBoolTemplate(lambda);
```

This is the error I get with clang 3.7.0:

```
Error(s):
source_file.cpp:32:5: error: no matching function for call to 'voidToBoolTemplate'
    voidToBoolTemplate(lambda);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
source_file.cpp:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (type-parameter-0-0)>' against '(lambda at source_file.cpp:25:19)'
auto voidToBoolTemplate(std::function<void(Arg)> func)
```

Assigning the lambda to std::function and then calling the function works.

```
auto lambda = [](int x)
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
};

std::function<void(int)> foo = lambda;

voidToBoolTemplate(foo);
```

In addition, if I use a specific type for the argument I can pass a lambda:

```
auto voidToBoolNonTemplate(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    return [&](int arg)
    {
        func(arg);
        return false;
    };
}

auto lambda = [](int x)
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
};

voidToBoolNonTemplate(lambda);
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

A live demo: http://rextester.com/COKT94318

Comment: Thanks, apparently my searching capabilities are not as good as I thought.

Comment: Do you really want to convert the lambda to a `std::function` though? In this case you want to convert one lambda to another lambda.

Comment: As demonstrated in the linked question, inferring the arguments to a lambda is hard. But if you don't mind specifying the type at the point you call `voidToBoolTemplate` you can just make the `Arg` (or `Args...`) another template parameter that needs to be specified: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QBrYUC46WIJLtdfD

Comment: @ChrisDrew can I convert it to a lambda without auto return type dedcution? I need to support pre C++14 compiler.